# python3 class generates same random value with unittest

Tags: python-3.x, random, python-unittest

This is an exercise from exorcism.io that I need to generate a random name with the class is initialized. One of the unit test cases is failing because the random string is same across two instances of the class. If I run the code outside of unittest, it appears to work correctly. Could it be that the var is pointing to the same address space in unittest?

```
import string
import random
import unittest


class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.reset()
        print('Name at Init', self.name)

    def reset(self):
        for _ in range(5):
            new = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) + str(random.randint(100, 999))

        self.name = new


class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    if not hasattr(unittest.TestCase, "assertRegex"):
        assertRegex = unittest.TestCase.assertRegexpMatches

    name_re = r'^[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$'

    def test_names(self):
        # Set a seed
        seed = "This is some seed text"

        # Initialize RNG using the seed
        random.seed(seed)

        # Call the generator
        robot = Robot()
        name = robot.name

        # Reinitialize RNG using seed
        random.seed(seed)

        # Call the generator again
        robot.reset()
        name2 = robot.name
        self.assertNotEqual(name, name2)
        self.assertRegex(name2, self.name_re)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
    # print(Robot().name == Robot().name)   # Returns False



F
Name at Init WY294
======================================================================
FAIL: test_names (__main__.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.......robot.py", line 42, in test_names
    self.assertNotEqual(name, name2)
AssertionError: 'WY294' == 'WY294'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the second call to seed in your test. The random number generator will always generate the same sequence for a given seed, so by calling the seed twice you are rewinding the sequence and that is why you get the same values.